# Why does ionic serve not work i get error?

Tags: ionic-framework, mobile, progressive-web-apps, serve

im taring to open my app in  browser

i use ionic serve but i get this error

> ng.cmd run app:serve --host=localhost --port=8100
>   [ng] The run command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.

[ERROR] ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code 1).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOokR.png)

Comment: Are you sure you are in your project directory?

Comment: Yes this is new project